# Java SQL looping though List of Strings[]

Tags: java, arrays, string, list

So I have a list of strings being returned from a DB query:

```
List<String[]> = getSqlReults();
```

The way the results are being return is in a name value pair:  E.g

```
name                       value
test                         0
test2                        2
```

And so on.

Now I need to loop though the list and if the `name = "test`", then store the value in a variable.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Why you are not limiting your sql result to meet your condition? It is much faster to test those condition in SQL rather than using loop in java. DB are design for such operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like

```
List<String[]> data = getSqlReults();
String result = null;
for (String[] str : data) {
    if ("test".equals(str[0])) {
        result = str[1];
        break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `Iterator` to iterate over the list:

```
List<String[]> list = getSqlResults();
String testValue = null;
...
for (Iterator<String[]> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    String[] nameValue = iterator.next();
    if(nameValue[0].equals("test")) {
        testValue = nameValue[1];
        break;
    }   
}
```